# How to Convert Android project into Google Api project

Tags: android

i developed android application in normal android2.1, i want to use Google map in my application. can i convert my android2.1 application into Google API application. I add maps jar file in my normal android application. but its not working. It throws an error like 
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:".

Any one know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Which Google API do you mean?

Comment: i need Google API 2.1, it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup you can,

Right click on the project name in the Project Explorer like so

[image]

Click on Android, you should see a Screen like this

[image]

Go ahead and select the Google API version that you want your app to be targeted to (Assuming you have downloaded the Google API SDK package)

[image]

Click ok and you are good to go!

Comment: Anytime Selva, please 'accept' the answer if it works for u :)

Comment: Thanks Selva, do let us know if u have any other queries :)

Comment: i have one more doubt, i changed that android project into google Api project, but it throws NoClassDefFoundError when i run my application

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:"target no."** in project.properties. 
Use this code in Manifest.

```
<uses-sdk        
        android:targetSdkVersion="target no."/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And have to create an **AVD** of **GoogleAPi** too to run the app.

If you didn't find Any Google Api in any version of android in **Android SDK & AVD Manager**, then do update and install Google APi for your desired version.

Hope this help you.